# GoogleTV LiveTV Capture

Tags: android, screenshot, video-capture, google-tv

I'm developing an APP for GoogleTV and I was wondering if it's possible to have some kind of service (running in the background) that when someone presses a button on the remote while watching LiveTV, a screenshot (or even video) of the TV show was sent to my APP.

Is this kind of behavior supported?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this kind of behavior supported?

No, sorry. We have no access to the television stream.